# Workflows: Apply a workflow to a single page in the pages library

Tags: workflow

I had an odd request from a BA in my project. They have a sub site, and they only care about changes made to the landing page. Is it possible to have an approval workflow apply to only one page and not the whole library?

I should also add that custom code would be used if there was no alternative.

Comment: does it need to start automatically when a major version is checked in?

Comment: Just when the user presses submit for approval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow would fire on every item, but you could always put some logic into the workflow so that the desired page is the only one it would execute the full logic.

Something as simple as a Yes/No field or choice field added to the metadata for the pages library would help.  Any page you'd want to execute the workflow on you set to Yes.  Then in the workflow logic, you'd do something like If column = Yes Do X Else End the workflow.

Comment: I have also come across such requirement a few times, is there any way to avoid the initiation form for items on which workflows do not execute full logic?

Comment: You wouldn't use manually initiated workflows or workflows with initiation parameters for this, just use standard on creation/on edit workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this by creating a new content type for the landing page, and attaching the workflow to just that content type, not the pages library itself

Comment: Would I (or the BA) be able to change the content type of the page?

Comment: Probably. Can't tell you the exact permissions, but I'd say someone with contributor rights (or at most full control rights) on the site should be able to do it. If you are going to try it out, I should point out that you will also need to create a copy of a page layout to attach to the new content type.